# Print something if the date changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

What exactly I am trying to do here is when Tomorrow comes (00:00) it should print `Yes`

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

r = True
rr = True
while r:
    Today_Date = date.today()
    while rr:
        Tomorrow_Date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        if Today_Date == Tomorrow_Date:
            print("Yes")
```

Comment: ...and what went wrong? From what I can see you should start by moving `Tomorrow_Date = ...` line in front of the `while` loop. You won't want to recalculate `Tomorrow_Date` every millisecond as you will never reach it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it now, your rr while loop will continually run and update `Tomorrow_Date`, and when the day rolls over, it will update before it has a chance to be compared to `Today_Date`. You should set both `Today_Date` and `Tomorrow_Date` outside that loop, and only update them when the dates change.

This should do the trick:

If you want two loops for other reasons:

```py
import datetime

r = True
while r:
  rr = True
    Tomorrow_Date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    while rr:
        if datetime.date.today() >= Tomorrow_Date:
            print("Yes")
            rr = False
```

Or as a single loop:

```py
import datetime

r = True
Tomorrow_Date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
while r:
    if datetime.date.today() >= Tomorrow_Date:
        print("Yes")
        Tomorrow_Date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

It might be a good idea to add a time.sleep() in to slow down the loops, depending on how accurate you need to be also.

Comment: If you don't want to wait until midnight to test this, you can change to ```datetime.datetime.today()``` and ```datetime.timedelta(seconds=X)```

Comment: Yeah i just change time to 23:59 from windows settings